# jQuery mouseout if function

Tags: jquery, if-statement, focus, opacity, mouseout

How can i set up a jQuery function that, when the user moves the mouse out of a div, will detect whether an input within the div is in focus and then change the div's opacity if it is not in focus?

So far I have tried using this code:

```
  $("#navbar").mouseout(function(event){
    if $(#navbarsearch.is( ":focus" )){
      //Animation Complete
    } else {
      $("#navbar").css('opacity', '0.8');
    }
  });
```

Comment: where is the code? what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using is(":focus") to determine if the input is focused should do the trick.

```
$('#div').on('mouseleave', function() {
    if($('input').is(":focus")) {
        $('input').fadeTo(duration, opacity);
    }
});
```

Comment: I only want the opacity to change if the input is not in focus though.

Comment: Never mind, I used an else and applied the opacity change there instead of in the initial if. Works great, thanks.